# How to put many psmatrix figures as graphics with subcaption? (or similar solution)

Tags: floats, psmatrix

I have an image created with \begin{figure} and inside \psmatrix.

How could I put 6 similar images as a 2 x 3 matrix?
similar to 
[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks}%[pdf]
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-blur}
\newpsobject{cnodeblue}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue}
\newpsobject{cnodepink}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink}
\newpsobject{cnodegreen}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green}
\newpsobject{psframegray}{psframe}{fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,shadow,blur}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\resizebox{3cm}{!}{    % if you want to resize
\psset{framearc=0.2, shadowcolor=black!70, shadowangle=-90, unit=1.0cm}
\def\pscolhookii{\hskip 2cm}

\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=1.9, colsep=2.9]% defines the distance between two frames
%
  &
  [name =Vecino1]
  \psframegray(.00,.00)(3.5,1.7)
    \pspolygon(0.5,0.2)(0.5,1.2)(2.3,1.2)(2.3,0.2)
    \rput[t](2.3,-.15){Vecino 1}
    \\ %[0.88cm]
  &
  [name =Vecino2]
  \psframegray(.00,.00)(3.5,1.7)
    \pspolygon(0.5,0.2)(0.5,1.2)(2.3,1.2)(2.3,0.2)
    \rput[t](2.3,-.15){Vecino 2}
   \\
%
  [name =SA]
  \psframegray(.00,.00)(3.5,1.7)
    \pspolygon(0.5,0.2)(0.5,1.2)(2.3,1.2)(2.3,0.2)
    \rput[t](2.3,-.15){Solución Actual}
   &
   [name =Vecino3]
  \psframegray(.00,.00)(3.5,1.7)
    \pspolygon(0.5,0.2)(0.5,1.2)(2.3,1.2)(2.3,0.2)
    \rput[t](2.3,-.15){Vecino 3}
%
\end{psmatrix}
%%% Links
\psset{linewidth=3pt, linecolor=red, arrows=->, nodesep=4pt,  linearc=0.25, angleB=180, shortput=nab, npos = 0.4}
\ncline[nodesepA = 2.0cm,nodesepB=0.5]{SA}{Vecino1}%
\ncline[nodesepA = 3.0cm,nodesepB=0.5]{SA}{Vecino2}%
\ncline[nodesepA = 3.7cm,nodesepB=0.5]{SA}{Vecino3}%

}\\[0.5cm]
%\vspace{2.85cm}
\caption{Forma 1 de Generar Vecinos}\label{Forma1GenerarVecinos}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I preferred to compile your pstricks code as standalone, using `includegraphics` in the main file, which makes a neater code. It has to be compiled with pdflatex.

I introduced an all-in-one macro with only one argument ( the text) for your fancyframes, in order to avoid repeating several time the same code, and gave as much as possible length parameters in function of the `unit`. This makes it easier to scale just setting `unit=…`. As a result the only parameters that require manual adjustment on scaling are the values of `nodepA` and `nodesepB`, and the code is more readable.

```
\documentclass[10pt,pdf]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pstricks}%
\usepackage{pst-node, pst-eps}
\usepackage{pst-blur}
\newpsobject{cnodeblue}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue}
\newpsobject{cnodepink}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink}
\newpsobject{cnodegreen}{cnode}{fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green}
\newpsobject{psframegray}{psframe}{fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,shadow,blur}

\newcommand*\myfancyframe[1]{\psframegray(0.0,0.25)(3.5,1.95)
    \pspolygon(0.5,0.575)(0.5,1.575)(2.3,1.575)(2.3,0.575)\rput[b](2.3,-0.5){#1}} %2.3,-0.05

\begin{document}

\footnotesize
\psset{framearc=0.2, shadowcolor=black!70, shadowangle=-90, unit=5mm}
\def\pscolhookii{\hskip 2\psunit}
\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=2.1, colsep=2.9]% defines the distance between two frames
%
  &
  [name =Vecino1]
\myfancyframe{Vecino 1}
    \\ %
  &
  [name =Vecino2]
\myfancyframe{{Vecino 2}}
   \\
%
  [name =SA]
  \myfancyframe{Solución Actual}
   &
   [name =Vecino3]
   \myfancyframe{Vecino 3}
%
%%% Links
\psset{linewidth=3pt, linecolor=red, arrows=->, nodesep=4pt, linearc=0.25, angleB=180, shortput=nab, npos = 0.4,nodesepB = 0.15}
\ncline[nodesepA = 2.2]{SA}{Vecino1}%
\ncline[nodesepA = 3.5]{SA}{Vecino2}%
\ncline[nodesepA = 3.7]{SA}{Vecino3}%
\end{psmatrix}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the main file itself, I used the `floatrow` package that's designed to make that sort of things. You can have a matrix of figures (`floatrow` environments, individual caption only) or a matrix of subfigures (`subfloatrow` environments, with subcaptions and a global caption).

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}

    \usepackage[margin = 2.5cm, nomarginpar]{geometry}%
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{subcaption} 
    \usepackage{floatrow}
    \captionsetup{font =footnotesize}
    \captionsetup[sub]{font =scriptsize}

    \setlength\intextsep{20pt}

    \begin{document}
   Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. 

 \begin{figure}[!ht]
 \floatsetup{captionskip = 8pt}
    \ffigbox{
    \begin{subfloatrow}[3]
    \ffigbox{%
    \includegraphics{genvecinosA}}%
    {\caption{workflow $S1$}\label{fig: wfs1}}%
    %
    \ffigbox{%
    \includegraphics{genvecinosA}}%
    {\caption{workflow $S2$}\label{fig: wfs2}}%
    %
    \ffigbox{%
    \includegraphics{genvecinosA}}%
    {\caption{workflow $S3$}\label{fig: wfs3}}%
    \end{subfloatrow}%
    \vspace{1\baselineskip}

    \begin{subfloatrow}[3]
    \ffigbox{%
    \includegraphics{genvecinosA}}%
    {\caption{workflow $S4$}\label{fig: wfs4}}%
    %
    \ffigbox{%
    \includegraphics{genvecinosA}}%
    {\caption{workflow $S5$}\label{fig: wfs5}}%
    %
    \ffigbox{%
    \includegraphics{genvecinosA}}%
    {\caption{workflow $S6$}\label{fig: wfs6}}%
    \end{subfloatrow}}
{\caption{A $ 2 ×3 $ matrix of subfigures}\label{matrix}}
\end{figure}
   Some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text. 

    \newpage 
    Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.
 \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \begin{floatrow}[3]
    \ffigbox{%
    \includegraphics{genvecinosA}}%
    {\caption{workflow $S1$}\label{fig: wfs1}}%
    %
    \ffigbox{%
    \includegraphics{genvecinosA}}%
    {\caption{workflow $S2$}\label{fig: wfs2}}%
    %
    \ffigbox{%
    \includegraphics{genvecinosA}}%
    {\caption{workflow $S3$}\label{fig: wfs3}}%
    \end{floatrow}%
    \vspace{1\baselineskip}

    \begin{floatrow}[3]
    \ffigbox{%
    \includegraphics{genvecinosA}}%
    {\caption{workflow $S4$}\label{fig: wfs4}}%
    %
    \ffigbox{%
    \includegraphics{genvecinosA}}%
    {\caption{workflow $S5$}\label{fig: wfs5}}%
    %
    \ffigbox{%
    \includegraphics{genvecinosA}}%
    {\caption{workflow $S6$}\label{fig: wfs6}}%
    \end{floatrow}
\end{figure}
   Some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text some more text.

    \end{document}
```

*Matrix of subfigures:*

[image]

*Matrix of figures:*

[image]

Comment: perfect! but I was trying copyng & pasting your code to make any tests and obtain this http://sensa.square7.ch/hdhfd5.jpg only a part of the psmatrix!!. ANOTHER thing: Do you think could be a good idea obtaining .eps files and then use subcaption package in the main file??? I n this case, how to obtain an eps from code instead a pdf?

Comment: Knowing not you actual code, I have no idea why you obtain only part of the psmatrix only. I obtained first an .eps, using TeXtoEPS from pst-eps, but the bounding box was much larger than the actual psmatrix (about twice its width!), and I ran into problems on manually correcting it, then converting to pdf. That's why I used the `standalone` class, that produces directly a cropped .pdf. For the use of `subcaption`, it is not limited to .eps files, but I don't know it well, and I preferred to use `floatrow`, which cooperates with `caption`/ `subcaption` anyway.

Comment: the code is exactly what you have posted in your fantastic answer!. I copy & paste the code you posted. LATEX + DVItoPS + PStoPDF

Comment: I've just tested the code for the image with Latex + `dvips -E` (to  obtain an .eps file instead of .ps). The problem is the bounding box as calculated  by TeXtoEPS is wrong, as often happens when mixing text and pure graphics. You can see it clearly if you launch simply dvips (without -E) and ask to see the resulting .ps file in gsview *with the bounding box*. So it's definitely vbetter to compile with pdflatex and the pdf option for the document class, unless you have very serious reasons to go the other way.

Comment: Thank you. When I use pstricks I always use LATEX, because PDFLATEX gives me problems. It´s a little complicated for me because I don´t know how to use many options(-shell-scape). I click the PDFLATEX button in winedt, an obatin this http://sensa.square7.ch/snap01226.jpg So... I´ll try in the next hours. and put as solved!! Thank you for all.

Comment: With latex + `dvips-E`, you obtain an eps with a wrong bounding box. But you can obtain a coorect pdf from it, using `epspdf` (it's *not* eps2pdf), and more specifically `epspdf-extra`, its version for Windows: it's a lua script that converts to pdf and crop the real image.

Comment: I was trying a little more, but no succes. I´m in the final days of my grade project, and I use any graphs as jpg, but the quality is regular. Is possible you help me give me this 5 images as eps?. I suposse that this is not much correct. https://www.dropbox.com/s/xgcpxn8nlwhx4gy/stack-favor-TEX.ZIP